# Snowflake flatten how to?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, flatten

I have a scenario where data is in below format in SNOWFLAKE SQL. Column AGREEMENTS is framed using listagg

[image]

I would like to flatten column "AGREEMENTS" and format the table as below . Requesting help

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to do something along these lines:

```
SELECT x.{list of fields}, y.value::varchar as agreements
FROM x,
LATERAL FLATTEN(input=>SPLIT(x.agreements,',')) y;
```

Comment: Thank you @Mike Walton

Answer (score 1):

[SPLIT_TO_TABLE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_to_table.html) is the function you are looking for. Given you have so many columns I have not typed them all out. You can use `t.*` to get them all.

```
SELECT 
    t.well,
    t.well_co,
<snip>
    a.value::text AS agreements,
    t.agreements_count
FROM table t,
    table(split_to_table(t.agreements, ',') a
```

Comment: Sorry, Simeon, didn't mean to step on your answer.  I'll leave mine up incase the OP really wanted to leverage flatten.

Comment: @MikeWalton no stepping on at all, I was going comment on your answer that I bet you by 30 seconds. But decided that was low value.. Both are very valid methods, and I used to do it your way, but recently found SPLIT_TO_TABLE so went for that.

Comment: Thank you @SimeonPilgrim